# What is the clock idle state by looking at this SPI timing diagram?

Tags: spi

The SPI clock polarity(CPOL) value is either zero or one and the actual value of the SPI clock in idle determines the value. For instance below SCLK is zero in idle and we can say that CPOL is zero:

[image]

But I encountered another diagram one such as below:

[image]

It is not explicit to me above whether CPOL is zero or one because both clock pulses and a line is drawn. Any idea what is CPOL by looking at the above diagram?

Answer (score 1):

Two lines means that the actual value does not matter. (Your device ignores the clock before the falling edge of /SYNC.)

Let's look at [Wikipedia's timing diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface#Clock_polarity_and_phase):

[image: SPI timing diagram]

Your device samples the data on the falling edge of the clock, and expects a rising edge of the clock after /SYNC goes low, so you need CPOL=0, CPHA=1.

Comment: Different MCUs have different meaning for the CPOL and CPHA bits, so if some generic diagram says how they are defined in this diagram, double check if the MCU being used has same or different notation

Comment: @Justme The MCU SPI mode should be set and in a way to match to the diagram in my question to have a successful communication. And STM32 defines CPOL by looking at idle state of the clock. But in my case, the idle state of the clock is undefined. That is my confusion.

Comment: @pnatk well if you have a specific chip or datasheet then link to them. The details might be in the timing parameters so some parameters might be allowed to be infinite or zero. And the possibility is also that the polarity is irrelevant as long as the data is updated and loaded at correct edges. Many SPI Flash chips are like this and support Mode 0 and Mode 3.